# Pairing same-index items in two lists as target and dependency in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have the example makefile below:

```
list1 = foo.txt bar.txt
list2 = foo bar

.PHONY: ${list2}

all: ${list1} ${list2}

${list1}: ${list2}
    @echo $@ $<
```

This produces the result

```
foo.txt foo
bar.txt foo
```

But what I want is

```
foo.txt foo
bar.txt bar
```

How can I do this? Just stripping `.txt` would work in this case and ignore `list2`, but not in the real file I am trying to work with. I need to pair members of lists across a large number of targets and substitutions.

Comment: `${list1}: ${list2}` sets the contents of `${list2}` as the prerequisites for **every** element in `${list1}` it doesn't do running pairs. GMSL might have something to make this easy but without that I think you get to play recursive loop games or create a third list dynamically of some separator then use `$(join)` to join the three lists and then `$(foreach)` over the joined list where you `$(subst)` the separator out and then `$(eval $(firstword $(val): $(lastword $(val)))` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

As Etan points out, after you expand the variables make sees:

```
foo.txt bar.txt : foo bar
```

Make is simply not going to somehow infer that you really wanted to say `foo.txt` depends on `foo` and `bar.txt` depends on `bar`: there are many ways make *could* interpret this.  The way it DOES interpret it, is if you had written:

```
foo.txt : foo bar
bar.txt : foo bar
```

which is why you get the results you do.

Your example is not very specific, so it's hard to help you. For example you show your two lists of files as being related by filename.  If that's really true, then you have no problem.  Just use this:

```
list1 = foo.txt bar.txt

.PHONY: ${list2}

all: ${list1}

%.txt: %
        @echo $@ $<
```

If the files you're building and using for prerequisites have no relationship (by name) to each other that you can describe with a pattern, then you have larger problems.